# circular route testing issue

Tags: python, algorithm

Here is the problem statement and I find two different solutions, post problem statement and solutions, my question is, wondering whether it is necessary to check if 4 consecutive runs will produce circle? And why check 4 consecutive runs, other than other numbers -- like 3 consecutive runs? Thanks.

**Problem Statement**

Given a sequence of moves for a robot, check if the sequence is circular or not. A sequence of moves is circular if first and last positions of robot are same. A move can be on of the following.

```
  G - Go one unit
  L - Turn left
  R - Turn right
```

Examples:

```
Input: path[] = "GLGLGLG"
Output: Given sequence of moves is circular 

Input: path[] = "GLLG"
Output: Given sequence of moves is circular
```

**Solution 1**

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-given-sequence-of-moves-for-a-robot-is-circular-or-not/

**Solution 2**

[Check If there exists a Circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967020/check-if-there-exists-a-circle)

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: You want someone write this Code?

Comment: @Arman, I edit the post to make it clear what is the problem statement for this problem. Please feel free to let me know if anything unclear.

Comment: Any length sequence without a G is circular, so yes, you should check any sequence length, and not just 4s.

Comment: @gariepy, so the answer here is wrong? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967020/check-if-there-exists-a-circle

Comment: @beaker, what are the differences? Appreciate for a bit more inputs. :)

Comment: @beaker, the SO question mentioned -- "robot never leaves the circle" for some radius, I think it means he same thing -- which means the robot returns to its original point -- which is the same as the question I post here. If my understanding is wrong, please feel free to correct me. :)

Comment: @beaker, for the SO question you mentioned, for itself, wondering whether it is necessary to check if 4 consecutive runs will produce circle? And why check 4 consecutive runs, other than other numbers -- like 3 consecutive runs? Thanks.

Comment: These are two different problems.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, thanks for the first problem I posted in my post (other than the SO link to the problem I quote), it only needs to check if there is a circle when passing the path once, but for the SO problem I quote, it involves checking infinite times of running path, correct?

Comment: @LinMa Yes, that's my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1 and Solution 2 appear to be working on different questions. Both involve a robot making a sequence of moves, but the question for Solution 2 has the robot repeat the sequence an *infinite* number of times.

- Question 1. Run the sequence once. Is the robot at its initial position?
- Question 2. If the sequence were run infinitely, could the robot's route be contained in a finite circle?

The second question seems much more interesting, so I focus on it here.

As noted in Solution 2, a single run has two effects: rotation (direction the robot ends up facing) and displacement (movement of the robot to a new position).

There are three general types of rotation:

- **No rotation**. In this case, you can solve the problem with just 1 run.

  - If displacement is zero, an infinite number of runs can be contained in a
    finite circle. You just need to plot the robot's full route and compute the
    needed size of that circle.
  - If displacement is non-zero, an infinite number of runs leads to infinite
    displacement and thus cannot be contained in a finite circle.
- **Rotation of 90 degrees** (i.e., once to the left or the right). In this
  case, you need to make 4 runs. After that, you'll be back to the initial
  orientation and you can solve the problem using the same logic described for
  the no-rotation scenario.
- **Rotation of 180 degrees** (i.e., twice to the left or the right). In this
  case, you need to make 2 runs to get back to the initial orientation. Solve
  in the same way.

Comment: Super smart answer FMc, a dumb question, for the problem statement I posted in this post, and for this problem => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967020/check-if-there-exists-a-circle, are they the same or not? I read the comments from @beaker and feel confused, and your advice is highly appreciated. :)

Comment: @LinMa The two questions are different. See the updated Note in my answer.

Comment: Thanks FMc, want to double confirm my understanding is correct, for the first problem I posted in my post (other than the SO link to the problem I quote), it only needs to check if there is a circle when passing the path once? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa Yes, for Solution 1's question, a single run will tell you everything you need to know -- specifically, did the robot return to its initial position?

Comment: Thanks FMc, I read again for this reference answer => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967020/check-if-there-exists-a-circle/28969617#28969617, I think it should check for both every 2 run and every 4 run? In this implementation, it only checks every 4 runs, seems wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa You never need to check **both** 2 runs and 4 runs; rather, you need to check only one or the other, depending the rotation involved (90 degrees vs 180 degrees). Also, checking 2 runs is purely a speed optimization: it doesn't give you any more information than checking 4 runs (because 4 runs == 2 runs done twice); rather, it just does the work faster if you are dealing with extremely long sequences. The same could be said regarding the no-rotation case: checking only 1 run is just a speed optimization (because 4 runs == 1 run done four times).

Comment: Thanks FMc! Mark your reply as answered. Will grant bounty reward later when time threshold passed. :)

Comment: @LinMa You're welcome. It was a fun problem to think about!